# Load model variables when eager loading resources in Laravel 4

Tags: php, orm, model, laravel

I am returning JSON data from a REST API in which I eager load related models (resources in this case).

```
// In my controller (FooController.php)
public function show($id)
{
  return Foo::with('bar')->find($id);
}

// In my model (Bar.php)
class Bar extends Eloquent {

  public $baz = 1;

  public function foo()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Foo');
  }

}
```

How could I also return `$baz` while using `with('bar')` and keep objects relations? A way I could, in my view/controller, use something such as `$foo->baz`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with an accessor. Since $baz is not an actual model attribute (well, I assume that this is the case from your question), you can do the following:

```
public function getBaz()
{
  return $this->baz;
}
```

See the [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for more info.

Comment: Okay, but how can I call `getBaz()` when it gets attached by using `with()`? Should `baz` be automatically passed with the model?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You want to get the variable in the `with`?

Comment: I have that http://paste.laravel.com/oH5 in my model loaded by the `with` in the `FooController`, but when I `var_dump` the JSON returned, `baz` is not there.

Comment: After further research this is related to this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/112 in which I understand I will need to manually add the value.